# Laravel Dusk, DatabaseTransactions not doing the RollBack

Tags: rollback, laravel-dusk

I'm using Laravel Dusk, the following Register test works fine, except that it doesn't rollBack the transaction (i.e. the user record created on 'Register' always stays in the DB). **My tables are all set to use InnoDB engine.**

Any ideas of what is going on? I have put Logs in many places and nothing looks particularly wrong. I don't get any errors at all in laravel.log file either.

```
use DatabaseTransactions;

protected $connectionsToTransact = [ 'mysql' ];

/**
 * A basic browser test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->type('name', 'Automated User')
                ->type('email', 'autoemail@hotmail.com')
                ->type('password', 'aaaaaa')
                ->type('password_confirmation', 'aaaaaa')
                ->press('Register')
                ->assertPathIs('/login');
    });

}
```

This is my connection in config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => 'innoDB',
    ],
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to update a model after the assert, but it doesn't work either. It seems like it's all DB transactions in general not being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `DatabaseTransactions` in Dusk tests. Since a real browser is opening your website, your test runs in a different process.

You have to reverse the changes yourself, e.g. by deleting the registered user.

Comment: So the official Database section of testing documentation is meant for HTTP tests only?

Comment: What documentation do you mean? Dusk or Laravel?

Comment: This documentation only applies to pure Laravel tests like `$this->get('/');`. These tests don't make "real" HTTP requests, they only pretend to. So they use the same database connection and can be capsuled in transactions.

Comment: Makes sense. Having that section next to the Browser tests seems a little bit misleading to me. Thank you.

Comment: They added a note on the Dusk page for Laravel 5.5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#migrations

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/dusk#migrations says (for Dusk) "When your test requires migrations, like the authentication example above, you should never use the RefreshDatabase trait. The RefreshDatabase trait leverages database transactions which will not be applicable across HTTP requests. Instead, use the DatabaseMigrations trait." Unfortunately, this has 2 problems: it calls `migrate:fresh` without seeding, and it's super slow if one has lots of migrations (compared to `use DatabaseTransactions`, which unfortunately can't work in Dusk).