# Initialize database for dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I am working on a laravel php application.

I want to automated tests with dusk.

What i want to do when launching tests is first create and initialize a dedicated database.

I want this database to be destroyed at the end of the tests

Is there a way to do that properly with dusk or should i do it manually by Hand ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Dusk, DatabaseTransactions not doing the RollBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542889/laravel-dusk-databasetransactions-not-doing-the-rollback)

Comment: No i want to describe all records i want to put in my database from test class